# CORS issue with proxy.conf.json in Angular App

Tags: angular, proxy

I've seen other similar issues here on Stack Overflow but so far nothings quite done anything for me yet.

I have an angular app serving to http://localhost:4200. 
I have a backend at http://localhost:8080/myApp/

I'm trying to set reach the backend from my frontend with the following call:

```
public getPeople(): Observable<PeopleModel[]> {
    return this.http
        .post(API_URL + '/getPeopleDetails', {})
        .map(response => {
            const people = response.json();
            console.log(people);
            return partners.map((people) => new PeopleModel(people));
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

the API_URL is set to http://localhost:8080/myApp

My proxy config looks like the following:

```
{
    "/myApp/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/myApp",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite" : {"^/myApp" : "http://localhost:8080/myApp"}
    }
}
```

My package.json has the following:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-conf proxy.conf.json",
```

The error I'm receiving when trying to run the app is a CORS one and a 403.

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/myApp/getPeopleDetails: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What is your 'backend'?

Comment: A spring boot app that has a several endpoints defined

Answer (score 3):

At the root of your application parallel to package.json file, create a new file
**proxy.config.json**

```
{
"/api*": {
    "target":"http://localhost:8080",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

Now in your **package.json** in scripts: {}, add the following flax with file name **proxy.config.json** to **start"**

```
{
"name":"xyz",
"version":"1.0.0",
"license":"MIT",
"angular-cli": {},
"scripts": {
    "start":"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "test":"ng test"
}
```

}

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already have all of this so it doesn't really help with trying to get the proxy to work.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall in any case?

Comment: Give me time till tomorrow, I too dealt with this long back. Let me have a look at my configs, ll get back to you.

Comment: @RunFranks525 I just checked. I have just got a file at the root .typingsrc and have as {
  "rejectUnauthorized": false,
  "registryURL": "https://api.typings.org",
  "httpProxy": "http proxy",
  "httpsProxy": "https proxy",
} This works for me. Also put the proxy in .npmrc file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that the option should be "--proxy-config", not "--proxy-conf" in "start": "ng serve --proxy-conf proxy.conf.json"

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass backend url without "api". Following another tip on proxy.conf.json:

```js
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target":"http://localhost:3000",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/myApp"
    },
    "secure":false
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server